# Chern-Simons, holography, and bibliography

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, ads-cft, holographic-principle, chern-simons-theory

I am looking for review papers / online talks on Chern-Simons theory with particular focus on the gravitational dual description within the AdS/CFT framework.